# Laravel send message to WhatsApp

Tags: laravel, whatsapp

I need to send a message via WhatsApp after the client performs an action.

1. Is it possible from Laravel?
2. Does it cost? Do I have to pay WhatsApp?
3. Is a business account required?
4. Is it allowed or considered SPAM?

Comment: This is not coding question. But yes its possible, just change your notification driver. There are many services who offer whatsapp as a service and they usually charge money. See https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-laravel-php-notification-channel-whatsapp-twilio for example

Comment: Check this article i thing it's will help you : https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-laravel-php-notification-channel-whatsapp-twilio

Answer (score 3):

Answer in your questions :

1 - Yes you can and this article will help you : [Laravel-WahtsApp-Api](https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-laravel-php-notification-channel-whatsapp-twilio)

2 - Yes it's not free and the below quote from some article

> For session messaging, Twilio WhatsApp API pricing is the simplest. It
> has a fixed price of $0.005 USD per message.

Check this article : [Whatsapp Business Price](https://respond.io/blog/how-to-choose-a-whatsapp-partner-whatsapp-business-api-pricing/#:%7E:text=For%20session%20messaging%2C%20Twilio%20WhatsApp,%240.02%20per%20message%20fee%20thereafter.)

3 - Yes it's required business account .

4 - I thing this quote enough answer :

> A WhatsApp message template is a message format that can be reused to
> message users once they have opted-in and given your app permission to
> send them messages. Template messages are used to help maintain
> high-quality content and avoid spam in the ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
My intention is to send a message after the customer places the order. This is possible? Or is the client required to start the chat on WhatsApp?

Comment: Thank you too,  actually you must read from WhatsApp business api , because this service is a new and maybe there a lot of changes so go to this link : https://faq.whatsapp.com , and go to chat tab you will find your answer there.

Comment: If this answer help you , give me up vote and set it as answer of question , thank you .

Comment: @AbdAbughazaleh Is it possible bidirectional messaging? I have a chat on my laravel app and want to send messages to whatsapp - thats fine. But can i receive the whatsapp messages in my laravel chat?  Does the API provide this ?

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=number&text=Hola%20este%es%20el%20mensaje" >Mensaje a whatsapp</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for (const numb in numbers) {
                whatsappnumbers.push(
                    `<li><a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${numbers[numb]}&text=${encodeURIComponent(@json($win->name))}'>${numbers[numb]}</a></li>`
                )
            }
            prizeText.innerHTML = whatsappnumbers;
```

Comment: This is not what OP is looking to do.